# Can I collect unemployment in this situation?

Tags: united-states, self-employment, unemployment, pennsylvania

I was employed (W-2) on a contract for almost 2 years and the the contract ended. Then I took a job 2 weeks after the contract ended which did not work out for me after being there for a very short time.

My question is, can I collect unemployment for the contract position that ended, even though I did work for a couple days after this? This is probably one of the more uncommon situations and I wasn't sure.

Comment: Have you actually asked the unemployment agency or whatever you call it?

Comment: Were you a contract employee (W2) or independent contractor (1099)?

Comment: Hart CO:  I was employed as W2

Comment: did you quit the 2nd job or were you terminated ? The point of unemployment is to get people through until they find a job, so I would be surprised if you could collect unemployment after you quit the 2nd job. edit: Do apply. The worst thing that happens is that they tell you no.

Comment: Xyious: that’s good advice. I guess I don’t have much to lose by applying. Sometimes it helps just talking it through with someone. Thank You.